# How can SQL Server be used to efficiently store website page views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am currently recording basic page views on a website using a single column, incrementing by one on each page load.

This gives a limited, very general view of the most visited pages, without taking into account pages being repeatedly loaded by a visitor, or being visited by search bots, etc.

Without worrying about these, I would like to efficiently track webpage visits, to allow querying for more detail, such as the most popular page today, or most popular this week.

Storing each view as an individual record would surely be quickly inefficient, and the data required doesn't need that level of detail.

Comment: What's the web environment?  ASP.Net/IIS?

Comment: If I understand what you are after, I would say a base table with all the page names in it, then a child table that would consist of the following columns.  Reference to Page, visited-datetime, useragent-nvarchar(100), username-nvarchar(100) [not sure if you have this], Referrer-nvarchar(200).  Add a new row for every vist.

Comment: @DMason The environment is ASP.NET in IIS with MSSQL.

Comment: I once wrote analytics code that tracked page views/hits by session.  It involved using a master page, session start/end events, and session variable(s).  When the session end event fired, the relevant data (including user agent) would be saved to a database.  You mentioned bots--I had difficulty dealing with this.  I tried filtering by the user agent string, using an AJAX no-bot control, et al.  I eventually gave up and went with Google Analytics.

Comment: @Dbloch This is the sort of approach I would have gone for, but wouldn't this quickly become inefficient? Recording the user agent and referrer would be a bonus, but not required, particularly due to the storage required.

Comment: @DMason In this case the figures don't need to be critically accurate, but just give a general picture of popularity. Perhaps an alternative would be to use the Google Analytics API to fetch page visits, with the bonus of really good accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question, you would have to provide your storage requirements and limitations, as well as the information that you want to store to identify page views.

In terms of pure storage efficiency, your existing logging is, i'd say, the most efficient way of storing page views, but realistically, this data is not very relevant without other pieces of information that give you a better picture, as you mentioned, tracking either the user, IP address and other non-sensitive information will give you a better panorama of the activity in your site.

I would suggest an approach that gives you both meaningful information and analytics capability in the following form:

- Keep a log for all page views in a table that will store information such as:

  - IP
  - Page (either the address, or if you're using MVC, the Controller and Action)
  - User Agent
  - IsMobileRequest? (Optional, in MVC you can access it through the Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice property)
  - TimeStamp

Additionally, you can have another table that stores the summary for the visits of all pages for a given period (for example, by month) that is updated using a SQL Server Job every month, retrieving records from the previous table, filtering them, creating a summary record in the monthly summary table and deleting them from the PageViews log table. This table would look similar to the one you already have, with maybe a few additional columns that contain figures such as different IPs count, most popular browser, amount of mobile visits and maybe an average visit hour range (all of them calculated by the job using the Log table).

This way, you can always have information about your page visits for the last month and statistic summaries for the monthly activity of your site, effectively using your available storage and providing you with a more rich source of analysis about your site's users.